# Laravel Sanctum default model customization

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent, laravel-sanctum

I use in my Laravel application `MongoDB as a database driver using composer package:

https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

By default, Laravel models extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class.

But when I use `MongoDB then my models must extend the` Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model` class instead of default Laravel class.

How I can now replace Laravel Sanctum default extending model class `Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken` to `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`.

**Example**

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Sanctum;

// use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;                      // Replace this class
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;                          // To this class
use Laravel\Sanctum\Contracts\HasAbilities;

class PersonalAccessToken extends Model implements HasAbilities
{
    // sanctum model
}
```

Now I can do this inside the `vendor` folder but I think it's the incorrect way. How to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: you can create a class: `PersonalAccessTokenMongodb` and define his prototype like that `class PersonalAccessToken extends Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model implements HasAbilities` but i don't know if you can override default models for Laravel Sanctum however that's possible with Laravel Passport: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#overriding-default-models

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create a custom PersonalAccessToken (you can just copy the original one "Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken.php")
then just change

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
```

for

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model
```

and finally in \Providers\AuthServiceProvider

you must add in the boot function

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(PersonalAccessToken::class);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work .

Answer (score 1):

in my search I found this package:
[Laravel-Sanctum-Mongo](https://github.com/Zach-Lu/sanctum-mongo)

It can serve you, basically it is just installing

Or

Step 1:

Copy this Model `\Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken` and paste in your custom model `\App\Models\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken`

Step 2:

Find the `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` and replace with `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;`

Step 3:

In the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` add this:

```
// Loader Alias
$loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();

// SANCTUM CUSTOM PERSONAL-ACCESS-TOKEN
$loader->alias(\Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken::class, \App\Models\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken::class);
```

and Ready, work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had also to add in the `vendor` folder `NewAccessToken` file this:

```
use App\Models\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/259) sanctum only support extending the default model and are probably not going to consider adding an interface.
But we can trick autoloader into loading our class instead of the default one.

Here is how to do it:

**Step 1**: Copy the `/vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/PersonalAccessToken.php` file to `/app/overrides/PersonalAccessToken.php`

**Step 2**: Edit the `/app/overrides/PersonalAccessToken.php` and replace `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`; with `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`;

**Step 3**: Edit your composer.json file and edit the autoload section to look like the following:

```json
"autoload": {
   "exclude-from-classmap": ["vendor\\laravel\\sanctum\\src\\PersonalAccessToken.php"],
   "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/",
      "Laravel\\Sanctum\\": "app/overrides/" 
   }
},
```

**Step 4**: run `composer dump-autoload`

This fixed my issue in the windows machine but the solution might not work for different OS because I've not tried them all. (Please comment your os name if this worked in your os)

Credits to https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/issues/263